# What actionable steps can I give to an unintentionally careless programmer to improve?

Tags: mentoring

Consider a programmer who has become known for writing careless code. More specifically spelling mistakes and generally mistakes related to not reading things properly.

Although not having dyslexia, he describes his situation as follows: He feels he struggles to read individual letters in words, but rather reads words as recognizable patterns.

What actionable steps, processes or assistance can I offer to him to improve in this space?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is a good fit for Workplace SE. A psychologist of behavioral therapist may have an answer for you. As far as I can understand either this person has an undiagnosed issue, or he just doesn't read things carefully enough. Maybe tell him to spend some time carefully reading and then writing down all the requirements before starting on a task?

Comment: Are you a supervisor or a peer?

Comment: A more senior peer. I am encouraged to mentor those junior to me.

Comment: Between your questions and the answer below I am now confused. Does this person have trouble reading requirements, or does he make mistakes in his own code? If so, does your IDE not provide any support for this sort of thing? Is no testing done to ensure that code doesn't fail because of simple mistakes like wrong variable names?

Comment: @AndreiROM - wouldn't a consistently misspelled variable still work?

Comment: @JeffO - indeed it would. As such, I don't know why it would even be an issue, except if it comes up in code reviews, however this would not be career breaking, like the OP implied in the original question. Basically I want to know more about the nature of the mistakes this person is making, because it sounds a lot more serious than simply calling a "counter" ***"countr"***.

Comment: Indeed spelling mistakes are minor but do cause technical debt: For example if something is spelled incorrectly in a database it will slow down another developer later who has to write a procedure. He now needs to intentionally misspell columns and may start mixing correct spelling with incorrect spelling.
That said, other mistakes that have been made include mixing up two similar variables causing bugs; or mixing up code by placing it in the wrong files (leading to the incorrect code being executed)

Answer (score 9):

A good IDE will take care of many of those problems.  Suggest he switch to one that has automatic spell checking, highlights undeclared variables and other bugs, auto completion/suggestion, and other features designed to catch typos.

Answer (score 3):

The first step would be code reviews. Before any code is accepted, it gets reviewed by someone. Spelling mistakes, especially those that make it impossible to find things, must be fixed before the code is allowed in. (I once spent ages trying to find someone else's code where the code was handling "receipt"s, to find that their code was handling "recipe"s. Fixing that at review time would have been a lot less work).

Then ask him to seriously look at what tools he has available to help. In my environment, I have one tool to rename anything (so if I find a method "examineRecipe" which examines receipts, one command will rename it everywhere), a spelling checker (which works better with comments because variables are most often not in correct English), and compiler settings that find anything suspicious and don't allow it. As a software developer, it is *his* job to know his tools and to use them in the best possible way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are referring to the quality / readability of the code, and not outright syntax errors which should be caught by the IDE, take this approach:

(1) Tell your programmer that what he is writing is not just for himself - his teammates and any future programmers that might come along.

(2) Tell him that by not taking a little extra time to review his code before checking it in, he causes everyone else - including, possibly, his future self, to be confused by what they are reading.

(3) Tell him that as a team player, he is *expected* to avoid causing others to be confused, which lowers everyone's quality and productivity - in other words the team suffers.

(4) Tell him that you or other team members will be conducting code reviews with him before he checks in his code to ensure everyone has a shared understanding of what he is doing.  Tell him that the expectation is that the number of issues should be going *down* over time.  And, any issues that are found, he'll have to fix before he is allowed to check in the code.

If he refuses to change, then it is probably time to let him go.  By doing the above, you'll have a document trail for your manager, which should make it easy.

Hopefully, he'll recognize that his actions do affect the team, and make an effort to change which you can monitor with the code reviews.

Comment: One of the critical parts is making sure he has to do the fixes. And I like the make sure he understands that there is an expectation that the number these types of changes will go down over time. If you clearly say, this is a showstopper for us for you to continue to be careless, he will improve or be asked to leave.

Comment: If the programmer has some sort of disability which affects his ability to read words as a series of letters rather than the entire word (my daughter has this disability) it is unfair to label his problem "carelessness".  It isn't a matter of refusing to change.  If he refuses to acknowledge that he has a problem that's one thing, but another entirely if he is aware of the problem and requires some help to work around his disability.